# why we need to use AsEnumerable() method?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, ef-code-first

This code causes a NotSupportedException.

```
var detailList = context.Details.Where(x => x.GetType().GetProperty("Code").GetValue(x,null).ToString() == "00101").ToList();
```

But this code works.

```
    var detailList = context.Details.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.GetType().GetProperty("Code").GetValue(x,null).ToString() == "00101").ToList();
```

MSDN says:

[- AsEnumerable() Returns the input typed as IEnumerable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb335435(v=vs.100).aspx)

[- DbSet Is an IEnumerable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696460(v=vs.113).aspx)

So why we need to use AsEnumerable() method?

Comment: Why are you using reflection when you could just use `var detailList = context.Details.Where(x => x.Code.ToString() == "00101").ToList();`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`DbSet` is also `IQueryable`.

`IQueryable` has its own set of LINQ extension methods that translate expression trees into SQL, and do not support reflection.

By calling `AsEnumerable()`, you change the compile-time type of the expression to `IEnumerable<T>`, forcing the extension methods to bind to the standard LINQ ones.

If you prefer to run your query on the server, you should build an expression tree instead of using reflection.

Comment: Your explanation is not so esay to understand(a lot of Terms) but I like it(+1). Something new not the standard answer.

Answer (score 3):

The first query attempts to have the query provider translate the query into SQL and execute it against the database.  It fails to create a valid database query, so it fails with the error mentioned.

Using `AsEnumerable` types the query as an `IEnumerable<T>`, rather than an `IQueryable<T>`, statically, and as such ends up calling the LINQ to objects version of the query methods, pulling the entire table into memory and then performing all of the operations within the application.

Answer (score 0):

When you're querying an `IQueryable<T>`, your method gets translated via an `Expression Tree` into SQL. `AsEnumerable` to change the compile time type to `IEnumerable<T>` and to bring all the entities from your database into memory, where you can query them via reflection via `LINQ to Objects`.